# Have an extra required error validation I can't figure out where it comes from...can't submit

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an extra required error validation I can't figure out where it comes from which prevents me from submitting the form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue with invisible widget (widget's visible property set to false). You can try to:

- make the widget(s) visible and then enter value in runtime
- make field(s), bound to the widget(s) optional (maybe you'll need to
  regenerate the form)
- change validation rules for the widget(s) (onValidate event handler)
- remove extra field(s) and widget(s)

You can toggle widgets visibility in editor using this button(show hidden widgets):
[image]